# Why this linked list prints from last input? C linked-list program

Tags: c, linked-list

So I have this simple linked list program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct record record;
struct record {
    char name[32]; 
    float score;
};

typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    record data;
    node *next; 
}; 

int main() {
    char data[100];
    char name[32];
    float x;
    node *p, *head;
    int counter = 0;

    head = 0;

    while ((fgets(data, 60, stdin) != NULL) && counter <= 3) {
        p = (node *) malloc (sizeof(node));

        sscanf(data, "%s %f", name, &x);
        strcpy(p->data.name,name);
        p->data.score = x;
        p->next = head;
        head = p;

        counter++;
    }

     printf("-----------------------\n");
     while (p) {
         printf("%s %f\n",p->data.name, p->data.score);
         p = p->next ;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

And this is the input and output:

```
 //input
 bob 10
 shiela 5
 john 1
 elisa 10
```

---

```
 //print input
 elisa 10.000000
 john 1.000000
 shiela 5.000000
 bob 10.000000
```

Why is it that it start printing from last input?

How can i print this starting from the first data i entered?

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're getting the nodes in reverse order is because this code:

```
p->next = head;
head = p;
```

inserts node at the *beginning* of the list, such as:

```
head -> null
head -> A -> null
head -> B -> A -> null
head -> C -> B -> A -> null
```

and so on.

Then, when you traverse from `head` to `null`, they *appear* to come out in reverse order but, in actual fact, that's just an side effect of your insertion method.

If you want them inserted in the list in the "correct" order, introduce a `tail` pointer and code it thus:

```
p->next = null;      // new node will always be end of list
if (head == NULL)    // special trap for empty list
    head = p;        //     means set up head
else                 // otherwise
    tail->next = p;  //     current tail now points to new node
tail = p;            // make new node the tail for next time
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply.. I see.. it adds to the beginning.. I thought I was printing in reverse or a linked list prints in reverse by default.. thanks I'll try to figure it out how to add at the end of the list

Comment: @Noob, see my update, it basically involves keeping track of the tail and adding after that. Downside is that you need slightly different code when adding first node.